# How to check if custom action is running in deferred or immediate execution using WIX C#?

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer, installshield-2012

Is there a better way than catching an exception thrown when attempting to read a session variable that is not accessible in deferred mode? 
Thanks

Comment: `Is there a better way` means that you want something better compared to something you are doing/have currently. So, mention it in your post first :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at Session.GetMode(InstallRunMode), analogous to the [Session.Mode property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371674). Note that there are three InstallRunMode values that correlate to the in-script execution scenario you're asking about: Scheduled, Rollback, and Commit.